# phpmyadmin page is not opening in xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed xampp server in my pc. First time creating database and insert data into database using phpmyadmin page was error free. For some table more than 1GB size i changed some configuration file settings like memory_limit, max_data_size. When I restarted the server and open the phpmyadmin page it is showing nothing (no error, no data). I don't understand the problem, already undo all configuration changes but still not working. 
In MySQL log getting the following status :

```
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-14 22:22:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300324
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 300333; transaction id 171
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200214 22:22:31
2020-02-14 22:22:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: check if mysql is running as service and look into mysql logs for errors

Comment: edit my question, add the error log

Comment: enable php errors https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/5193536  and see if it gives an error.  Else you have to go back in your changes and take every change onne at a time.